# I'm unable to add password to newly created user

Tags: 14.04, sudo, adduser, useradd

I just created a new account with Administrator privileges but cannot set up the password to activate account. I don't know how to set-up the account password via terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `passwd`. From [man passwd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/passwd.1.html):

```
DESCRIPTION
       The passwd command changes passwords for user accounts. A normal user
       may only change the password for his/her own account, while the
       superuser may change the password for any account.  passwd also changes
       the account or associated password validity period.
```

To use, run the command `passwd`. This will attempt to change your password - which you don't want.

So to change another user's password, use `passwd username`. However, your regular user won't have permission to do this - only root can change another user's password.

As [the man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/passwd.1.html) says:

```
 A normal user may only change the password for his/her own account
```

and

```
superuser may change the password for any account.
```

So finally, you need this command:

```
sudo passwd username
```

And you will see this:

```
$ sudo passwd askubuntu
  [sudo] password for tim: 
  Enter new UNIX password: 
  Retype new UNIX password: 
  passwd: password updated successfully
```

Comment: I follow through your advice and was able to set up the password successfully, however I still can not access the new account. It  accepts the password but the screen blinks and stays there as if there is no image to start.

Comment: this seems to be a totally different question now. I will post again. thanks

Answer (score 2):

From another point, I would recommend you to use the command `adduser` instead of `useradd`. When using the command `adduser` the system will ask you to enter the password of the newly created user, while the command `useradd` doesn't which I assume you used it to create your user.

```
$ sudo adduser abcd

Adding user `abcd' ...
Adding new group `abcd' (1006) ...
Adding new user `abcd' (1003) with group `abcd' ...
Creating home directory `/home/abcd' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
Enter new UNIX password:
```

You can use the command then `passwd` to change password as specified in TIM answer.